# module not defined in karma

Tags: node.js, angularjs, karma-runner

I want to run mySpec.js with karma in WebStorm 7. When I run karma, karma server starts on my browser but in WebStorm I am facing this error:

This is the error I'm getting

> ReferenceError: module is not defined
>       at null. (C:/Users/Babar/Desktop/angular/test/basic/mySpec.js:2:16)
>       at C:/Users/Babar/Desktop/angular/test/basic/mySpec.js:1:1 Process finished with exit code 0

here is my configuration file:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Nov 21 2013 03:05:08 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

module.exports = function
(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'test/basic/mySpec.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [

    ],


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera (has to be installed with `npm install karma-opera-launcher`)
    // - Safari (only Mac; has to be installed with `npm install karma-safari-launcher`)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows; has to be installed with `npm install karma-ie-launcher`)
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
    captureTimeout: 60000,


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

and here is my mySpec.js:

```
describe('filter', function(){
    beforeEach(module('Babar', []));

    describe("reverse", function(){
        it("should reverse a string",inject(function(reverseFilter){
            expect(reverseFilter("ABCD")).toEqual("DCBA");
        }))
    })
})
```

Please let me know what should I do ?

Answer (score 8):

Karma needs to pull in all your the files that you are working with.  It uses the `files` collection in its config to configure which files to pull in:

So this needs to be expanded:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'test/basic/mySpec.js'
],
```

To something like this:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'src/lib/angular/angular.js',
  'src/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'src/js/**/*.js',
  'test/**/*.js'
],
```

The error is indicating that the file that defines the module `Babar` has not been found in one of the files configured in the `files` list.

Comment: When I included
JASMINE,
JASMINE_ADAPTER,

I am getting this error
ERROR [config]: Error in config file!
 [ReferenceError: JASMINE is not defined]

So I included the jasmine.js and adapter.js files
and I'm getting this error
ERROR [config]: Error in config file!
[ReferenceError: JASMINE is not defined]

Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Including JASMINE and JASMINE_ADAPTER in the files array is applicable to Karma versions 0.8.x and down. It seems you are using Karma 10 so just remove those 2 lines from the files array since you are already loading Jasmine as the framework